# MOSS 2007 on Active Directory 2012

Tags: sharepoint, active-directory, sharepoint-2007, moss

I have a client who is upgrading parts of their Windows server infrastructure to Windows 2012. They have a MOSS 2007 installation on the same network currently.

Assuming that the WFEs and app servers (which run SharePoint Services) remain on Windows 2008 installations will the app servers be able to continue to run the AD imports successfully? Will adjustments need to be made? Or will it be outright incompatible?

I understand the best answer is to upgrade SP to 2010 or 2013 but am trying to understand all options. Thanks very much.